# GCC not recognize imread in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, gcc

I has compiled and linked OpenCV project with Visual C++ Express under Windows.
With GCC under Ubuntu is compiled but is link error:

```
finder.cpp|219|undefined reference to `cv::imread(cv::String const&, int)'|
```

I have added libraries:

```
-lopencv_calib3d
-lopencv_core
-lopencv_features2d
-lopencv_flann
-lopencv_highgui
-lopencv_imgproc
-lopencv_ml
-lopencv_nonfree
-lopencv_objdetect
-lopencv_photo
-lopencv_stitching
-lopencv_superres
-lopencv_ts
-lopencv_video
-lopencv_videostab
```

and for example cv:line proceure is OK, but only one error (so far) imread

Comment: It would be good to see the code here.

Comment: any chance, you're trying to compile the 3.0 branch instead of the 2.4 one? (imread has been moved to a new 'imgcodecs' module there some days ago) ? do a `git branch`, if it says 'master', you probably want to `git checkout 2.4` and recompile (again, all of this assuming, that you compiled the linux version from github src)

Comment: Yes, if I add -lopencv_imgcodecs it is OK!

Comment: please, reconsider, if you want the bleeding-edge 3.0 branch on linux, or the 2.4.9 one.

Comment: again, i'm just saying, i myself am all happy on 3.0, but you will have to adapt a lot of unexpected differences to 2.4, which are *not at all* related to the os switch, but only to the different code-base used.